# similar to flood fill in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I want to write a program which does not only fill the black area surrounding by white area; but it also makes the edge of each blob smoother. This programm will do something look like the pictures show in below.

**Orginal**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgzyypus5bfblb3/Original.PNG

**Wantted**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxv8uhfpr9e3414/edited.PNG

Flood filling for the black area surrounding by white area only is not enough. I also do dilate which make the area bigger (which I do not want) but it does not work well.

Can anyone give me some hint?

Thank you very much

Comment: please put your images *here*, not on dropbox. also, a question without code begs for downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to blur your image, then apply threshold to it.

1) cv::GaussianBlur   (use large kernel and sigma)

2) cv::Threshold      (I guess threshold value should be about 127)

This sequence should smooth edges of the blobs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying a [dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) after the flood fill.